# Use a dynamic match in XSLT

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an external document with a list of multiple Xpath like this:

```
<EncrypRqField>
    <EncrypFieldRqXPath01>xpath1</EncrypFieldRqXPath01>
    <EncrypFieldRqXPath02>xpath2</EncrypFieldRqXPath02>
</EncrypRqField>
```

I use this document to obtain the Xpath of the nodes I want to be modified.

The input XML is:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <id>1</id>
        <firstname>xyz</firstname>
        <lastname>abc</lastname>
        <age>32</age>
        <department>xyz</department>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

I want to obtain something like this:

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <id>XXX</id>
        <firstname>xyz</firstname>
        <lastname>abc</lastname>
        <age>XXX</age>
        <department>xyz</department>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

The XXX values are the result of a data encryption, I want to dynamically obtain the Xpath from the document and change the value of its node.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if something like this is possible in XSL 2.0. May be in 3.0 there should be some function evaluate() but I don't know any details.

But I tried some workaround and it seems to be functional. Of course it is not perfect and has many limitations in this form (e.g. you need to specify absolute path, you cannot use more complex XPath like //,  [], etc.) so consider it just as an idea. But it could be the way in some easier cases.

It is based on comparing of two string instead of evaluation string as XPath.

Simplified xml with xpaths to encrypt (I ommit the number for simplicity).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EncrypRqField>
    <EncrypFieldRqXPath>/Employees/Employee/id</EncrypFieldRqXPath>
    <EncrypFieldRqXPath>/Employees/Employee/age</EncrypFieldRqXPath>
</EncrypRqField>
```

And my transformation

```
    <xsl:template match="element()">
        <xsl:variable name="pathToElement">
            <xsl:call-template name="getPath">
                <xsl:with-param name="element" select="." />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$xpaths/EncrypFieldRqXPath[text() = $pathToElement]">
                <!-- If exists element with exacty same value as constructed "XPath", ten "encrypt" the content of element -->
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:text>XXX</xsl:text>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- This template will "construct" the XPath for element under investigation. -->
    <!-- There might be an easier way (e.g. some build-in function), but it is actually out of my skill. -->
    <xsl:template name="getPath">
        <xsl:param name="element" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$element/parent::node()">
                <xsl:call-template name="getPath">
                    <xsl:with-param name="element" select="$element/parent::node()" />
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$element/name()" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise />
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```